# Does BDE support SQL Server 2016?

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2016, bde

When I run the `bdeadmin.exe` to link SQL Server 2016 by `mssql` type, it just crashes.

Does BDE support SQL Server 2016 ? Thank you.

Comment: The BDE has been discontinued for many years, and was deprecated at least a decade ago,.so it's highly unlikely that it supports a version of SQL Server that is now five years old. You've had at least 10 years notice that you need to move away from the BDE - why haven't you done that long before now? It's been very well known that its days were numbered, and that number ran out years ago.

Comment: It's an old application, and it's still in use...T_T  .Thank you.

Comment: The dbGo ADO components are a better option for accessing SQL Server and have been included in the lower editions of Delphi like Professional for decades now. They first appeared in Delphi 5 in 1999 and are still in Delphi 10.4.1 in both 32 and 64 bit flavors. Over the decades lots of developers did the migration from BDE to dbGo.